# PHP 7.2 xml domdocument get nodevalue of given childnode value of sibling having attribute equal to

Tags: php, xml, xpath, domdocument

I've the following xml

```
<ReviseInventoryStatusResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <Timestamp>2019-01-02T15:42:31.495Z</Timestamp>
  <Ack>Warning</Ack>
  <Errors>
    <ShortMessage>Requested StartPrice and Quantity revision is redundant.</ShortMessage>
    <LongMessage>The existing price and quantity values are identical to those specified in the request and, therefore, have not been modified.</LongMessage>
    <ErrorCode>21917091</ErrorCode>
    <SeverityCode>Warning</SeverityCode>
    <ErrorParameters ParamID="ItemID">
      <Value>770386906435</Value>
    </ErrorParameters>
    <ErrorParameters ParamID="SKU">
      <Value/>
    </ErrorParameters>
    <ErrorClassification>RequestError</ErrorClassification>
  </Errors>
  <Errors>
    <ShortMessage>Requested StartPrice and Quantity revision is redundant.</ShortMessage>
    <LongMessage>The existing price and quantity values are identical to those specified in the request and, therefore, have not been modified.</LongMessage>
    <ErrorCode>21917091</ErrorCode>
    <SeverityCode>Warning</SeverityCode>
    <ErrorParameters ParamID="ItemID">
      <Value>770386906436</Value>
    </ErrorParameters>
    <ErrorParameters ParamID="SKU">
      <Value/>
    </ErrorParameters>
    <ErrorClassification>RequestError</ErrorClassification>
  </Errors>
  ...
  </ReviseInventoryStatusResponse>
```

I need to get the ShortMessage for the given ItemID that is found in ErrorParameters/Value where ParamID="ItemID"

I've been able to check if a node with the given value exists:

```
$xmlr = new DOMDocument();
$xmlr->load('ReviseInventoryStatusResponse_error.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($xmlr);
$xpath->registerNamespace('e', 'urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents');
$nodeExists=($xpath->query('//e:ErrorParameters[@ParamID="ItemID"]/e:Value[. = "770386906435"]')->length>0)?1:0;
```

then I tried to get its ShortMessage with

```
$xpath->query('//e:Errors[e:ErrorParameters@ParamID="ItemID"]/e:Value[.="770386906435"]/e:ShortMessage')
```

but got invalid predicate as expected since not find the right way to combine filters.

can pls suggest the right way?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are several ways

1. Select the `Errors` element node using nested conditions:
   `//e:Errors[e:ErrorParameters[@ParamID="ItemID"]/e:Value[. = "770386906435"]]/e:ShortMessage`
2. Select the `Value` element and use the `parent` axis 
   `//e:ErrorParameters[@ParamID="ItemID"]/e:Value[. = "770386906435"]/parent::*/parent::*/e:ShortMessage`
3. Select the `Value` element and use the `ancestor` axis 
   `//e:ErrorParameters[@ParamID="ItemID"]/e:Value[. = "770386906435"]/ancestor::e:Errors/e:ShortMessage`

If you use `DOMXpath::evaluate()` you can use `count()` and `string()` to fetch the scalar values directly. You might not even need to check if the node exists, because the result will be an empty string in this case.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($document);
$xpath->registerNamespace('e', 'urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents');
$nodeExists = $xpath->evaluate(
  'count(//e:ErrorParameters[@ParamID="ItemID"]/e:Value[. = "770386906435"]) > 0'
);

var_dump($nodeExists);

$shortMessage = $xpath->evaluate(
  'string(//e:Errors[e:ErrorParameters[@ParamID="ItemID"]/e:Value[. = "770386906435"]]/e:ShortMessage)'
);
var_dump($shortMessage);

$shortMessage = $xpath->evaluate(
  'string(//e:ErrorParameters[@ParamID="ItemID"]/e:Value[. = "770386906435"]/parent::*/parent::*/e:ShortMessage)'
);
var_dump($shortMessage);

$shortMessage = $xpath->evaluate(
  'string(//e:ErrorParameters[@ParamID="ItemID"]/e:Value[. = "770386906435"]/ancestor::e:Errors/e:ShortMessage)'
);
var_dump($shortMessage);
```

Output:

```
bool(true) 
string(56) "Requested StartPrice and Quantity revision is redundant." 
string(56) "Requested StartPrice and Quantity revision is redundant." 
string(56) "Requested StartPrice and Quantity revision is redundant."
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the XPath to fetch the short message, a quick way to check if there is a message is to just check if there are any results from the query...

```
$smgs = $xpath->query('//e:Errors[e:ErrorParameters[@ParamID="ItemID" and e:Value="7720386906435"]]/e:ShortMessage');
if ( count($smgs) > 0 ) {
    echo $smgs[0]->nodeValue;
}
else {
    echo "does not exist";
}
```